# Missing faces when transferring from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm not sure why, but whenever I try to transfer this .blend model from Blender to Unity, many of the faces are breaking. I'm not familiar on what to do to fix this. I'll give the steps I used to make it though. Basically, I made a UV Sphere and then used the bisect tool. I then tried using it in Unity, but it was missing faces. I figured it was an issue with the vertices, so I did some cleanup on the vertices using the Mesh > Clean Up tools. That just left it in even more of a mess. The following images show it in Blender and then in Unity. Blender's the good one and Unity's the really messed up one.

Blender Photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z7Pq.jpg

Unity Photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjUFm.jpg

Comment: Unity won't be drawing any backfaces for optimisation reasons, are you certain all your triangles have are facing in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Recalculate Normals` in Blender?